# getting images from SD card instead of array, how to do this?

Tags: android, arrays, image, sd-card

I learn about many examples of app code that has images stored in an array like the folowing example code posted below.  I always get code from websites that have the input as these silly arrays, instead it would be better to get all the images stored on my phone's SD card, can someone suggest some code that will achieve this.  I am stuck and really need some help.  or at least could someone point me in the right direction.thanks

```
  private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.pic01,
            R.drawable.pic02,
            R.drawable.pic03,
            R.drawable.pic04,
            R.drawable.pic05,
            R.drawable.pic06,
            R.drawable.pic07,
            R.drawable.pic08,
            R.drawable.pic09
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the mediastore for a list of images from the sdcard or a particular folder.

Check out the post and its links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12319614/328947).